# Edge not respecting transform-origin on SVG

Tags: css, svg

I have a vehicle I want to rotate dynamically as part of an SVG:

```
<g id="top-view-vehicle-12" transform="translate(17.000000, 25.000000) rotate(`${heading}`)" transform-origin="11 25" fill-rule="evenodd">
```

Works great in Chrome, but Edge doesn't respect the `transform-origin` and the vehicle is misplaced. Any idea how to keep the `<g>` element centered?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qpXYBy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unsurprisingly, `transform-origin` is not part of the spec:

https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#GElement

Trick was to apply the origin in the transform:

```
<g transform="translate(17.000000, 25.000000) rotate(${heading} 11 25)">
```

Comment: transform-origin is specified here: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/

Comment: @RobertLongson Absolutely, it is a CSS style. It is *not* an attribute on the `g` element, as I had been attempting to use it.

Comment: The link @RobertLongson posted specifies how transforms work on SVG elements: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#svg-transform


Edge is not honoring the specification here.